# How to add a link dynamically to product listing page without chaging phtml?

Tags: magento

I ant to add a link with each product on product listing page (link add to wishlist link). But I don't want to add it through changing "catalog/product/list.phtml".

Is it possible to do it though layout xml or jquery?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new block in XML, but you will also have to create a template file, assign that template to new block. To display it  in list.phtml you will nee to call $this->getChildHtml('wishlist_link_block');

Simplest and easiest solutions are sometimes the best so I really think that changing list.phtml is the best place to do it.

Comment: Hi, above solution will work for me. But still I will have to modify the list.phtml to add $this->getChildHtml('wishlist_link_block');

Comment: I want to this functionality as plug and pay. Means, if user installs my module, this link will automatically get added. Is this possible?

Comment: Add the block through an observer not in the phtml file. Look this : http://www.human-element.com/Blog/ArticleDetailsPage/tabid/91/ArticleID/77/Magento-observers-unique-layout-handles-page-views.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
  Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {     

      $$('.parent-class-of-all-products-wraper').each(function(c){

         c.insert(new Element("a",{id:"anch_id"}));

       });

   });
```

Comment: if consider default list.phtml then here you can loop on : $$('.products-grid> .item').each

Comment: If I need to add some product data as well like, product id. In that case, will it work?

Comment: yes it will work, but first give it a try to add only link, then update additional attributes to that link ...